# useState not updating[NOT AN ASYNC ISSUE]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm new to react hooks so I'm practicing with showing and hiding a div when checking and unckecking a checkbox input. The problem is that the state updates on the main file where I have the function that handles it but in the file where I actually have the div it does not update so it does not hide or display.

File that handles the change of the state:

```
import {react, useState} from "react";

export const Checker = () => {
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true)

    const clickHandler = () => {
        setChecked(!checked)
        console.log(checked)
    }
    return {checked, clickHandler, setChecked}
}
```

File where the checkbox is located:

```
import React from "react";
import { Extras, Wrapper } from "./extras.styles";
import { Checker } from "../hooks/useCheckboxes";

const Extra = () => {
    const {checked, setChecked, clickHandler} = Checker()
return <>
    <Extras>
        <Wrapper>
        
            <input type= 'checkbox' onClick={clickHandler} checked = {checked} onChange={e => setChecked(e.target.checked)}></input>
            
        
        </Wrapper>
    </Extras>
    </>
}

export default Extra;
```

File that contains the div i want to display and hide dynamically:

```
import house from '../../icons/house.png'
import { Wrapper } from "./foto.styles";
import { Checker } from "../hooks/useCheckboxes";
import { Inside, Middle} from "./foto.styles";


const Home = () => {
    const {checked} = Checker()

    return <>
    <Wrapper>
        <Inside>
            <Middle>
                {checked && <House src={house}/>}  
            </Middle>
        </Inside>
    </Wrapper>
    </>
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues are:

- `Checker` looks like you want it to be a custom hook, not a React component, so it should be called `useChecker` or something like that, not `Checker`
- You have both a change handler and a click handler. You should only have one. If you want the new state to come from the checkbox, you should use `e.target.checked`. If you want the new state to flip the old state, use the `clickHandler` you defined in `Checker`.
- You only need a fragment when enclosing multiple elements. If you only have one, you don't need a fragment.
- Because state setters [don't update the variable immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately), your `console.log(checked)` won't display the new value, but the old value - if you want to log the new value when it changes, use `useEffect` with a dependency array of `[checked]` instead.

```
const Extra = () => {
    const { checked, clickHandler } = useChecker()
    return (
        <Extras>
            <Wrapper>
                <input type='checkbox'checked={checked} onChange={clickHandler} />
            </Wrapper>
        </Extras>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like that

```
const {checked, clickHandler, setChecked} = Checker()
```

Or if you want to be able to make custom names then you need to use an array instead of an object.

the function return value.

```
return [checked, clickHandler, setChecked]
```

the function call

```
const [checked, setChecked, clickHandler] = Checker()
```

and for convention follow react hooks naming rules by renaming the function to useChecker() instead of Checker()